# AWS Lambda: Invoke function on successful completion of another

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, invoke, serverless

I have two Lambda functions:

- Func1
- Func2

Func1 gets invoked hourly on schedule (defined as Event in template.yaml).

I need to invoke Func2 on successful completion of Func1.

How do I achieve this without calling Func2 inside Func1 code?
Is there a way in CloudFormation template to achieve this? Using Events may be?

Comment: one possible way is to use SNS

Comment: Can you modify Func1 code at all or you just don't want to invoke Func2 from within Func1 but are able to modify Func1 code otherwise?

Comment: @Tommy I have access to func1 code. I was wondering if there was a different way to do it so that func1 can be kept modular.

Answer (score 3):

Step Functions is the service you want to use: https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/getting-started/

It is the "official" way to chain up you lambdas and I have actually implemented that kind of solution like 2 years ago. You can tweak the input and output parameters of every node of the lambda chain. And of course, you can write CF to provision a SF state machine.

You do need to change your Cloudwant event rule target from triggering a single lambda to triggering a SF state machine. But I believe that is not a major change at all.

I did have a bad experience maintaining the SF state machine JSON in Cloudformation, but that might have been improved and not too bad if your chain is only 2 lambdas. And now it seems that step functions has been much more powerful than just a lambda chaining service.

Comment: Thanks @congbaoguier I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to invoke Func2 directly from Func1 you can:

- Put a notification to an SNS topic in Func1 and then subscribe Func2 to that topic
- Put a message to an SQS queue in Func1 and then trigger Func2 using that queue
- Put a notification to an SNS topic in Func1 and then subscribe SQS queue to that topic and trigger Func2 off that queue. That's called [fanout pattern](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/queues-and-notifications-now-best-friends/) and is useful to implement parallel processing.
- Finally, use Step Functions especially if you implementing more elaborate workflow and not just stringing two functions together.
- You could even trigger Func2 off the CloudWatch log of Func1